# Getting 404 on Page/Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404

I am new to MVC, and in my MVC web application, I am having issues with 404 errors for a new page I just created.

My controller contains:

```
public ActionResult PageX()
{
    Return View();
}
```

I also have an associated view titled PageX.  However, if I attempt to navigate to PageX I receive a 404 error.  When I debug my application, it isn't even getting to my breakpoint at the action result.  Are there any other steps necessary when creating a new page so that the application is aware of it?

Comment: What is the location for your view i.e. PageX.cshtml ?? By default it will seach on View/yourControllerName/PageX.cshtml

Comment: I have PagesController and, within my Views folder, there is a Pages folder for the views associated with that controller.

Comment: Can you pls try steps as I have mention below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can additionally check two things:

1) Is your new controller inherting from controller base as of other working controllers.

2) Is your existing route definitions can allow the new controller/action or need to add new route?

Hope this help you...

Comment: Yes, adding a new route to my RouteConfig.cs file fixed the issue perfectly.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can return the view by explicitly calling it with the full path e.g.

```
public ActionResult PageX()
{
  return View("~/Views/Wherever/SomeDir/YourView.cshtml");
}
```

Hope this help!